# Jquery Content DIV SLIDE

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-selectors

I wanted to make the

(A)  http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#side-scroll

(B)  http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/steps.html

Hey all,

I am building  a customize slider.

I wanted the functionality of A and B mixed both

1) Boxes in A is going to be in different Tag/Category, so for 
example there's going to be Cat, Dog and Snake category.

2) Now i wanted when i do click on CAT the slider is going to slide that particular cartigory thats associated with the Tag, 
etc

3) If i do slide to CAT tag, it will just snap and the catagory will show up

help will be good, as i continue try figuring it out, hope im not confusing you guys.
or

OR THIS:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#hotelrooms and  http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#side-scroll

instead when u click 3, it slides to 3CONTENT when u lick 4 it SLIDES to 4 CONTENT

Comment: I'm not seeing the question here.

Comment: Jquery Content DIV SLIDE

So how can i get the scroller working with the snap functionality,

- and also when i do click a Tag, like 1, 2, 3, 4, it goes to the box thats associated with 1, 2, 3, etc

Comment: Post your HTML/Javascript so far, or even better create a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.com) for us to use.

Comment: You question is semi-clear. Say as per in (A) say 1=Cat, 2=Dog and so on. When you click on Cat, you want the slider below to move? If yes, why? What purpose it serves? Maybe more explanation will help understand your scenario better.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like this?
I have taken your reference (A) as an example.

```
$(".scroll-content div").click(function () {
                var pos = $(this).position();
                $('.scroll-bar a').animate({ left: pos.left }, 'slow');
            });
```

Check in action [here](http://jsbin.com/omeno5/3).

Update1: I updated the sample in above link, if that helps.

**Update 2:**

Sorry, I tried a bit but couldn't make it work entirely but here is something I have:

```
$(function(){
 $("div#makeMeScrollable").smoothDivScroll();
var ticker;
           $('.scrollingHotSpotRight').mouseover(function () {
               var counter = $(".scroll-bar").slider("value");
               var leftval = 0;
               ticker = setInterval(function () {
                   $(".scroll-bar").slider("value", counter);
                   counter++;
               }, 35);
           });
           $('.scrollingHotSpotRight').mouseout(clearStop);
           $('.scrollingHotSpotLeft').mouseover(function () {
               var counter = $(".scroll-bar").slider("value");
               ticker = setInterval(function () {
                   $(".scroll-bar").slider("value", counter);
                   counter--;
               }, 35);
           });
           $('.scrollingHotSpotLeft').mouseout(clearStop);

           function clearStop() {
               window.clearInterval(ticker);
           }
});
```

Comment: Ok so when user clicks 'Cat', the boxes will move with to position where images of cats begin? Is that what you mean? If so, where do you plan to put your tags? Do you have a proposed Design(image) for what you are looking for?

Comment: hey i wanted to extend this a-bit...so when the user hover over the right side...the boxes move including the scroll bar.
and if you hover over the left side, it scrolls back, its working, but not fullly, it's not moving the
scroll back with it and it's not reseting proporly.

like this: http://www.smoothdivscroll.com/basicDemo.htm

i have a extended version here: myislandshop.com/3 2.zip

Comment: GBS, any thoughts help?, i posted a zip of my files

Comment: I am looking at it. It is doable, so let me see.

Comment: HEY GBS quick question, how come when i try to add another tag like tag2..... by dublicating, it's not doing the samething, like it's not working

Comment: Didn't get that. Do you mean you are changing 0-4 to something else? Can you post sample code?

Comment: Basically duplicating this:   <prev><div class="tags">
        <ul>

        <li class="first">0-4</li>
        <li>5-8</li>
        <li>9-12</li>
        <li>13-16</li>
        <li class="last">17-20</li>
        </ul>

        </div>
</prev>
making another one and putting it above.

Comment: The click on li is bound to only those li inside .tags class. i.e. check the code block: $(".tags ul li").each(...) If you want to apply same logic to other just abstract the code into a function and apply it to .tags2 ul li as well.

Comment: Yep and that's what i did...which makes sense...but it does not move move the scroll-bar or div the same way like the DEMO..strange.i dublicated the code block and the CSS...put it right after "tag" and make the second one tag1

Comment: gbs any thoughts why this is happening?

Comment: HEy GBS need ur help quick: how can i write this more effiently where that

1) I can have about 50 scroll content on 1 page but not having the repeat the entire JS
implementation

http://jsfiddle.net/myislandshop/s5mgX/188/

Comment: You might want to turn the code into a jquery plugin which takes the scrollup/down elements as options.

Comment: You might want to take a look at some basic tutorials creating jquery plugin like this:http://devheart.org/articles/tutorial-creating-a-jquery-plugin/ to start with.

Comment: Something like this: http://jsbin.com/uquho4/edit There are some modifications to html i.e. added class to a, divs and changed css from #content to .content.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is utilize the step option in the scrollbar implementation, if I understand your question correctly.

```
//Modified from the Slider scrollbar demo
var scrollbar = $( ".scroll-bar" ).slider({
        slide: function( event, ui ) {
            if ( scrollContent.width() > scrollPane.width() ) {
                scrollContent.css( "margin-left", Math.round(
                    ui.value / 100 * ( scrollPane.width() - scrollContent.width() )
                ) + "px" );
            } else {
                scrollContent.css( "margin-left", 0 );
            }
        },
        step: 50 //<---This
    });
```

Or are you looking for someone to write the entire functionality of what you're asking for?

Comment: Yes, the basic or a head start  will be appreciated